# Sequence Applications

Tags: sequences-and-series

Sometimes in sequence type problems (arithmetic, geometric, involving a + (n-1)d, etc) involving real life applications, I find myself unable to know if I should include "just" the n, or (n-1) in the formula to count or not to count the extra term. When term numbers get really big and it's not as easily computable, I can't reasonably know if to add in the extra term or to not. How do I find out what to do and if to include the extra term or not? When doing my homework, I often get questions wrong by a very slim margin due to this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Often you know the first term of your sequence. Whether you call it $a_0$ or $a_1$, plug $n= 0 $ or $1 $ and see if you get the number. It is just a quick sanity check.

Comment: What if it's a question involving something like, "there are # of boxes/terms in the 3rd row from the bottom", then it's unclear? It's not really my first term but it is one of the only ones I know.

Comment: You have to understand what $n$ means, in the context of the problem. You can find out if $n$ or $n-1$ is playing that role by doing the quick test above

Comment: Do you mean that once I get the sequence formula, I test values of n to see if I get the correct answer, and if not, then opt for the alternate approach?

Comment: Sort of. Do that for the first term that you usually know.

Comment: For example, here: Boxes are stacked in a store display in the shape of a triangle. The numbers of boxes in the rows form an arithmetic sequence. There are 41 boxes in the 3rd row from the bottom. There are 23 boxes in the 12th row from the bottom. How many boxes are in the first (bottom) row? What is the formula for the nth term? I did a + (n-1)d = term, so a + 2d = 41, and a + 11d = 23. Solving, I get d = -2, a = 45. I plugged in and got the right answer. But say I would do a + d*n, as opposed to a + (n-1) * d, to verify my answer, I'd check and see if I get 41 when I plug in 3?

Comment: I think that you are not really understanding what $a$ and $d$ are. Forget the formula. Think of the meaning..write it as $a_n = a_0 + (n-1)d$ or $a_n = a_1 + nd $. See the difference now?

Comment: Indicate explicitly what elements are you equating. For example: $a_n = a_{10} + (n-10)d$, etc. In all the three expressions I gave, put $n=0,1$ and $10$, respectively.

Comment: Well the formula with nd is assuming that we are starting from the 1st term, not the 0th term.

Comment: That's the point: all expressions I put there are equivalent. Understand the meaning of it and use what is most convenient. You'll never have the sort of problem again.

Comment: Well how I understand it is a is what we start with, it's our starting point. D is the difference or whatever occurs to the starting value to give the next values.

Comment: Forget "a". Start indicating these terms as $a_n$, it'll be easier. "d" is ok. And what goes multiplying "d" is the issue here: this is how many steps you've given. What goes multiplying "d" is some blob, such that when you evaluate $a_n = a_k + {\rm blob}\, d$ at $n=k$, gives $a_n$. Think of $k$ as being $0$ or $1 $ for now, and look again at the previous examples I gave.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand it. It's the same issue as this question over here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285706/how-to-know-in-a-application-sequence-series-problem-which-variable-is-a-0-o?rq=1, I just can't really comprehend what to do with your advice.